# When I use selenium wire to find page elements and send data, you will be prompted "elements do not interact"

Tags: python, seleniumwire

When I use selenium wire's find_ Elements (by. XPath, '/ / input [@ class = "quantumwiztextinputpaperinputinput exportinput"]') returns my results when looking for page elements, but when I want to send data, it prompts me "element not interactive"，What's the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtIDq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clUK5.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not images

Comment: Please change those images to text